# mysql | Facet search advanced

Tags: mysql, database, facet

I have tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Computers'),
(2, 'Bikes');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fields` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `fields` (`id`, `field_name`, `cid`) VALUES
(1, 'Processor', '1'),
(2, 'Display', '1'),
(3, 'Brand', '2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fields_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `fields_values` (`id`, `field_id`, `field_value`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Intel Pentium 3'),
(2, 2, '27 inch'),
(3, 3, 'BMX'),
(4, 1, 'AMD Radeon'),
(5, 1, 'Intel Atom'),
(6, 2, '22 inch');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cid` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `cid`) VALUES
(1, 'Computer1', 1),
(2, 'Bike1.BMX', 2),
(3, 'Bike3', 2),
(4, 'Intel Atom', 1),
(5, 'Computer Radeon', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_to_fields_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_value_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `products_to_fields_values` (`id`, `product_id`, `field_value_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 3),
(3, 1, 2),
(4, 4, 5);
```

My request looks like:

```
SELECT ft.id field_id, ft.field_name, fvt.field_value, fvt.id field_value_id, COUNT( DISTINCT pid ) count
FROM FIELDS ft
JOIN fields_values fvt ON ( ft.id = fvt.field_id ) 
JOIN products_to_fields_values pfv ON ( pfv.field_value_id = fvt.id ) 
JOIN products pt ON ( pt.id = pfv.product_id ) 
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT ft.id field_id, ft.field_name, fvt.field_value, fvt.id field_value_id, pt.name, pt.id pid
FROM FIELDS ft
JOIN fields_values fvt ON ( ft.id = fvt.field_id ) 
JOIN products_to_fields_values pfv ON ( pfv.field_value_id = fvt.id ) 
JOIN products pt ON ( pt.id = pfv.product_id ) 
GROUP BY pt.id
)LJ ON pfv.product_id = LJ.pid
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 1, pt.cid ) 
GROUP BY ft.field_name, fvt.field_value
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This request will return (I'm trying to build faceted filter):

```
field_id field_name field_value field_value_id count
2        Display    27 inch     2              1
1        Processor  Intel Atom  5              1
1        Processor  Intel Pentium 3            1
```

But I have other values in this table: **fields_values** like: AMD Radeon and 22 inch.
Where is my mistake in the request?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I'm expect to getting result:

```
field_id   field_name   field_value   field_value_id   count
2          Display      22 inch       6                0
2          Display      27 inch       2                1
1          Processor    AMD Radeon    4                0
1          Processor    Intel Atom    5                1
1          Processor    IntelPentium3 1                1
```

Where count is a products count.

Comment: Please give give me in brief what result/output you want from these tables, so I can try to build my own query for you,
thanks.

Comment: Ready. Check my edit above.

Comment: I build query and I got the data what you want but not clear about count column, of which field count you want!!!

Comment: Count is a products count. Where is your query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work SQL, but im not sure you have build your structure correctly.

```
SELECT
  ft.id field_id, ft.field_name, fvt.field_value, fvt.id as field_value_id, COUNT( DISTINCT pid ) count
FROM products AS pt
JOIN products_to_fields_values AS pfv ON pfv.product_id = pt.id
JOIN fields_values AS fvt ON fvt.field_id = pfv.field_value_id
JOIN fields AS ft on ft.id = fvt.field_id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT ft.id field_id, ft.field_name, fvt.field_value, fvt.id field_value_id, pt.name, pt.id pid
FROM fields ft
JOIN fields_values fvt ON ( ft.id = fvt.field_id ) 
JOIN products_to_fields_values pfv ON ( pfv.field_value_id = fvt.id ) 
JOIN products pt ON ( pt.id = pfv.product_id ) 
GROUP BY pt.id
)LJ ON pfv.product_id = LJ.pid

WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 1, pt.cid ) 
GROUP BY ft.field_name, fvt.field_value
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In short - u have error in this line:

```
JOIN products_to_fields_values pfv ON ( pfv.field_value_id = fvt.id )
```

right one:

```
JOIN products_to_fields_values pfv ON ( pfv.field_value_id = fvt.field_id )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no product_id = 5 and field_value_id = 4 in that table: products_to_fields_values! Your query returns "AMD Radeon" with count 1 (should be 0).

Answer (score 0):

I tried for your question, check this query

```
select fValue.field_id, f.field_name as field_name, fValue.field_value, fValue.id as field_value_id
from products_to_fields_values as productValue
left join fields_values as fValue on(fValue.field_id=productValue.field_value_id)
left join fields as f on (fValue.field_id=f.id)
left join products as p on (productValue.product_id=p.id)
where p.cid=1
```

Comment: @user889349 check out this query, I will try to get count also.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure the problem, i.e. the 'missing' records, is being caused by the 'group by' commands. It's a bit difficult to come up with a solution for you as I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve. The expected result you posted hasn't helped me much in this regard.  The query you are trying to run is rather complex, and on a populated database is going to start running very, very  slowly. As such it would suggest a better database design is required. If you can explain what you are trying to achieve I will gladly look at a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the limit and where clauses this is the query you need to use:

```
SELECT
  fields.id AS field_id
, fields.field_name
, fields_values.field_value
, fields_values.id AS field_value_id
, COUNT(products.id) AS `count`
FROM fields_values
JOIN fields ON fields.id = fields_values.field_id
JOIN category AS field_category ON field_category.id = fields.cid
LEFT JOIN products_to_fields_values AS product_fields ON fields_values.id = product_fields.field_value_id
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = product_fields.product_id
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

This produces the following result:

```
| field_id | field_name | field_value     | field_value_id | count |  
+----------+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------+  
|        1 | Processor  | AMD Radeon      |              4 |     0 |  
|        1 | Processor  | Intel Atom      |              5 |     1 |  
|        1 | Processor  | Intel Pentium 3 |              1 |     1 |  
|        2 | Display    | 22 inch         |              6 |     0 |  
|        2 | Display    | 27 inch         |              2 |     1 |  
|        3 | Brand      | BMX             |              3 |     1 |
```

In your `where clause` you can specify

```
WHERE category.id IN (1)
```

to get the result you want.

The mistake you were making (and a previous answer as well) was that you were joining the category through the product giving you the *product_category* instead of the *field_category*.

When you applied a where condition on the *product_category*, it removed all products not part of the set, so you would never get the count = 0